# "плеваться желчью в кого-н": Is this a colloquial figurative expression to refer to someone arguing furiously?

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> **плеваться желчью в** кого-н

Is this expression usually used figuratively rather than in a literal sense?

On another note: Why does "желчь" take the instrumental case here, instead of the accusative? Is it because of a reflexive verb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Желчь figuratively means

> раздражение, язвительность, злость ( irritation, annoyance, anger, acrimony ) 
>   The usage is figurative, (an idiom "излить/изливать желчь" is more common )

The rule is

> После возвратных глаголов никогда не употребляются недушевленные имена существительные в винительном падеже, (Reflexive verbs never take an inanimate  noun in the accusative )

With animate nouns the situation is different. It's normal to use accusative in colloquial speech,but not in the written speech.

> Он всегда слушается мать и отца.(colloquial).Слушайся Анну.

Answer (score 3):

I might be flawed, but can't this be directly translated as

> spitting bile

in the sense of

> his response was full of bile and hatred

---

Oh, and I'd attribute `-ся` to "own" bile, it's not someone's else bile that gets figuratively thrown around.